# Excel VBA Incremental Column Summation and Updating

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to code a For Loop to sum incremental column and check against a total value.

If sum column G+H+I+..(last column) < Column AG then update Column G,H,I,.. to 0

If sum of column > column AG then last active column used in summation = sum of all columns minus Column AG.
Kindly refer to picture, cells highlighted in Yellow shows the intended macro.

To make the macro run faster the main code is written in nested If
When Column AG > 0 run the main code

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]

```
Sub Test()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set dm = Worksheets("a")
    Set CTOT = dm.Columns("AG")

    dm.Activate
    lastcol = dm.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    fz = dm.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


    For i = 3 To fz
        inventory = CTOT.Cells(i, 1).Value
        If inventory > 0 Then

            For j = 7 To lastcol
                sumdm = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(dm.Range(Cells(i, j), Cells(i, j + 1)))

                If sumdm < inventory Then
                    dm.Cells(i, j).Value = 0
                Else
                    dm.Cells(i, j).Value = sumdm - inventory
                End If

            Next j

        End If

    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I pretty much stuck but my current code seems to be giving me very odd data.
I think it might be because I am updating and running a loop at the same time but is not sure how to fix this or a better way to code this.

Comment: I don't get what the actual problem is? you say it gives you odd data but that doesn't explain much

Comment: The picture above After Macro is what i want my result to be.
Kindly refer to attached picture i edited to original post.
Instead of getting the result i want my macro is giving me:

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 534 2520 3680 3680 3680 6297
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 35288 39245 0 0 0 0 0
362 912 962 728 494 494 494 494 178

Comment: Couple of things I've picked up on: first when you get your `lastcol`, the way it is, it will include column **AG**. If you don't want that, you will have to subtract `lastcol` value by 1. Second, your `sumdm` is only giving you sum of 2 cells rather then a range. change it to `Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(dm.Range(Cells(i, j) & ":" & Cells(i, j + 1)))`

Comment: Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(dm.Range(Cells(i, j) & ":" & Cells(i, j + 1)))
This code gave me a runtime error "1004"

Comment: Sorry, that would. First set a range. To do that, first set your range variable as `Dim oRn as Range`. Then just before you get `sumdm`, have this `Set oRn = dm.Range(Chr(64 + 7) & i & ":" & Chr(64 + lastcol) & i)`. This will give you the range. Now you can get your sum by `sumdm = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(oRn)`. You wont  need the `For j = 7 To lastcol` loop. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could speed up your code by read and write at one like this

```
Dim data As Variant
' read data from sheet
data = Sheets("a").Range("A1: D100").value
' read/write value to data(i,j)
' smt.....

' then write to sheet
Sheets("a").Range("A1: D100") = data
```

I think you are toooooooooo lazy to setup properly your data type. This not Python ok?

```
Sub Test()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set dm = Worksheets("a")

    Set CTOT = dm.Columns("AG")
    Dim inventory, sumdm As Double

    dm.Activate
    lastcol = dm.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    fz = dm.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim data, ivn As Variant
    data = dm.Range(dm.Cells(3, 7), dm.Cells(fz, lastcol))
    ivn = dm.Range("AG3:AG" & fz)

    For i = LBound(data, 1) To UBound(data, 1)

        inventory = CLng(ivn(i, 1))
        If inventory > 0 Then
            sumdm = 0
            For j = LBound(data, 2) To UBound(data, 2)
                sumdm = sumdm + data(i, j)

                If sumdm < inventory Then
                    data(i, j) = 0
                Else
                    data(i, j) = sumdm - inventory
                    Exit For
                End If

            Next j

        End If

    Next i
dm.Range(dm.Cells(3, 7), dm.Cells(fz, lastcol)) = data
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: So my case it assuiming my data is from G3:O13

    data = Sheets("a").Range("G3: O13").value

    all my code 

    Sheets("a").Range("G3: O13") = data
    ???

Comment: I write code for you. test it. there is some place might need to fix. 1. fz = /...../ ;

Comment: First you read all data in worksheet to an 2-dimension array. Then you play around with data in the array. Finally you write the data to the worksheet. That how you can speed up you code. In my experient, you could save from several times to hunderds of time faster by using this technique.

Comment: thanks a bunch, i just starting to self learn vba will deep dive down online to learn about 2-dimension array.
The code looks to be working fine and is crazily fast compared to my previous flawed code.